# Kde uses Gnome notification system instead of knotify

Tags: gnome, gtk, notification, plasma

I tried to install kubuntu-active on the Kubuntu Trusty and it failed to start. So, I removed it and many packages has "active" in it name related to KDE Active. KDE runs ok now but one issue: It uses Gtk+ notifications instead of Knotify (although it is already running). The issue remains even after rebooting. How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens when you execute `killall notify-osd` in commandline?

Comment: When I kill notify-osd and when an app notifies, notify-osd runs again and I get notification in Gtk+ way again. By the way chromium-browser starts in Gtk+ UI instead of KDE UI and NetworkManager plasmoid doesnt run!

Comment: And when you kill both `notify-osd` and `knotify` and then start `knotify` again? GTK+ themes can be modified somewhere in **Control center** -> **Application appearance** -> **GTK** (might be named a bit differently).

Comment: When I did what you mentioned nothing changed.

Comment: Hi, I've the same issue in Kubuntu 14.10 and notify-osd installed.